# Find all possible latitudes/longitudes in 500 meter circle radius

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google map in my android application. and I have drawn a circle on specific latitude and longitude on the map, and the circle's radius is 500 meters. I want to find the maximum and minimum latitudes and longitudes in that circle, how to do this?

to explain my idea further, see the picture below:

[The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE6fR.jpg)

I want to calculate all of the possible latitudes and longitudes on that red circle, can someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: @RolandStarke sorry what do you mean?

Comment: @RolandStarke I'm planning to specify a longitude and latitude on the map, then draw a circle 500 meter radius around it. I want to find all the possible latitudes and longitudes that could be within this circle, how to do so?

Comment: Given that latitude and longitude are real numbers, there are an infinite number within the circle. Or do you have some given accuracy in mind?

Comment: As Roland Starke said, you can't get all the coordinates in that circle because well... There are too many

Comment: @RolandStarke how to calculate the distance?

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, but what do you mean by accuracy?

Comment: @DavidSeroussi how about getting the maximum and minimum ?

Comment: Well how granular a result do you want? Whole numbers/degrees? A certain number of decimal places/minutes and seconds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27943/5378743

Answer (score 1):

A single max and min for latitude and longitude is going to give you a squarish shape, which is not what the image suggests you're looking for. Furthermore, there will be infinite latitudes and longitudes within that area depending on how precise you want to get, so getting *all* of them is going to be a problem.

What I suspect you're after is a way to check if a specific latitude and longitude is within that circle. You can use the Pythagorean theorem for that:

[image]

Where 0.005 is based on a general approximation of 500 meters being 0.005 degrees on Earth.

Comment: Note: this math only works near equator because there 1 lon degree has a distance of 111km at the poles the distance is 0km.